# Why after I change my spark plugs and coils and when I looked had gas on one spark plug

Tags: ford, sparkplugs, escape

I have a 2006 Ford escape I changed the spark plugs and I changed the coils but it still has a very rough idle and it sounds as if it could be a problem I pulled one of my plugs out and it had gas on it I saw where there could be a few problems which narrowed it down but I wonder which problem it is it is a 2.3 4 cylinder engine

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Have you done (or had done) compression and leakdown tests?

Comment: Your check engine light is on? What are the trouble codes? If you don't have a code reader, you can get the codes read for free at most auto parts stores. Please write them down, we need the exact code numbers. You can edit your question to add the codes to it.

Comment: Also could be faulty injector. But codes and compression tests would be my first moves.

Answer (score 0):

Try swapping the coil from the cylinder with the wet plug, with one from a working cylinder, does the fault follow the possibly faulty coil?

If the fault stays with the same cylinder, try swapping the spark plug to a different cylinder.

In both cases if the fault swaps to a different cylinder, then you know you have found the faulty part.

If after these tests you still have a wet plug in the same cylinder, then possibly there is a wiring issue to the coil on that cylinder, or even an issue with the ecu.

Do these simple tests and report back.